# SPARK : Max number of executor failures (3) reached

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting above error when calling function in Spark SQL. I have written function in different scala file and calling in another scala file.

Ex: Function.Scala

```js
object Utils extends Serializable {
  
  
  def Formater (d:String):java.sql.Date =
  {
    
    
    val df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    val newFormat=df.format(d)
    val dat= java.sql.Date.valueOf(newFormat)
    
    return dat 
    
    
  }
  
}
```

I am calling above function in another scala file.

Registered UDF here :

sqlContext.udf.register("Formater",(s:String) => Utils.Formater(s))

and using here :-

```js
val startdate =sqlContext.sql("select  dateFormater(parameterValue) from Table").show()
```

If I remove the above function the code is running without any issue, If I include it is throwing me the above error.

Comment: find the failing tasks in the Spark UI - it will show the actual exception thrown from the task. The exception you wrote here is the end result of too many failures, but it's not particularly helpful in figuring out the root cause.